# How to insert values into nested table in python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have created a nested table in bigQuery and I would like to insert values into this table.

I know normally we can perform as below:

```
INSERT INTO `tablename`(webformID,visitID,visitorID,loginID,mycat,country,webformData) VALUES ('1',2,'3','4','5','6',[STRUCT('key2','b'),('k3','c'),('k4','d')])
```

where webform data is a nested column.

However, in python, how can we do this?

I can create a list as follows: `["STRUCT('key2','b')",('k3','c')]` but the 0th index is a problem while trying to insert.

Please advice
Thank you

Comment: Hi @SriHari, Can you provide the exact error message you are getting and share the code you are using

Answer (score 3):

You can insert data in the same order than the table was created.

Follow an example:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(JSON_FILE_NAME)
dataset_id = 'test'  # replace with your dataset ID
table_id = 'tablek1'  # replace with your table ID

schema = [
        bigquery.table.SchemaField('column1', 'STRING', mode='REQUIRED'),
        bigquery.table.SchemaField('parent', 'RECORD', mode='REQUIRED', fields = [
            bigquery.table.SchemaField('children1', 'STRING', mode='NULLABLE'),
            bigquery.table.SchemaField('children2', 'INTEGER', mode='NULLABLE')])
    ]

dataset_ref = bigquery.Dataset(client.dataset(dataset_id))
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)
table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
table = client.create_table(table)  # API request

# IF YOU NEED GET THE TABLE
# table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id) 
# table = client.get_table(table_ref)  # API request

rows_to_insert = [
    (
        "test 1", dict(children1 = 'test', children2 = 29 ),     
    )
]

errors = client.insert_rows(table, rows_to_insert)  # API request
print(errors)
```

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Hi @hkanjih thank you for your response.... I have just figured out the solution. There is no need to specify STRUCT in SQL command. We can provide list of tuples so that it can be passed to the query directly which can help in insertion.