# Error in Loading nested and repeated data to bigquery?

Tags: pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am getting JSON response from a API.
I want to get 5 columns from that,from which 4 are normal,but 1 column in RECORD REPEATED type.
I want to load that data to Bigquery table.
Below is my code in which Schema is mentioned.

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery

```
import pandas
import pandas_gbq



URL='<API>'

auth = HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password')
  
# sending get request and saving the response as response object
r = requests.get(url=URL ,auth=auth)
  

data = r.json()
```

----------------------json repsonse----------------

{
"data": {
"id": "jfp695q8",
"origin": "taste",
"title": "Christmas pudding martini recipe",
"subtitle": null,
"customTitles": [{
"name": "editorial",
"value": "Christmas pudding martini"
}]
}
}

---

```
id=data['data']['id']
origin=data['data']['origin']
title=data['data']['title']
subtitle=data['data']['subtitle']
customTitles=json.dumps(data['data']['customTitles'])
# print(customTitles)

df = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
'id':id,
'origin':origin,
'title':title,
'subtitle':'subtitle',
'customTitles':customTitles

    },index=[0]
)

# df.head()


client = bigquery.Client(project='ncau-data-newsquery-sit')
table_id = 'sdm_adpoint.testfapi'

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
    bigquery.SchemaField("id", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("origin", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("title", "STRING"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("subtitle", "STRING"),

bigquery.SchemaField(
        "customTitles",
        "RECORD",
        mode="REPEATED",
        fields=[
            bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
            bigquery.SchemaField("value", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),



])

    ],
        autodetect=False

    )
df.head()
job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df, table_id, job_config=job_config
)

job.result()
```

customeTitle is RECORD REPEATED fiels, which has two keys name and values, so I have made schema like that.
Below is my table schema.
[image: table schema]

Below is output of df.head()

jfp695q8    taste   Christmas pudding martini recipe    subtitle    [{"name": "editorial", "value": "Christmas pudding martini"}]
[image: df.head]

Till here its good.
But ,when I try to load the data to table it throws below error.

ArrowTypeError: Could not convert '[' with type str: was expecting tuple of (key, value) pair

Can anyone tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: Does this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55283128/how-to-insert-values-into-nested-table-in-python) help you?